# Gatsby / WebPack: How to build only used Components at build-time

Tags: webpack, gatsby

I've created a gatsby theme.
In this theme, I want to add all Components, that might be used by an user of the Theme.
That means, if a user import my theme in gatsby, he can choose via `/data/config.yml`, which components (like imageGallery, Maps, Slider) should be used in it's Gatsby-Page. The imports will be generated dynamically on build-time.

> *I don't go deeper within the technical implementation of that, it's only to give you some background for the following question.*

To make the user able to choose only the Components he need, I have to bundle ***all*** components into the delivered theme.
Let's say a user doesn't want to use the `Map` Component in his Page, so he don't configure it in his `config.yml`... and at least there won't be an `import Map from '...'` in any of the gatsby-pages at all.

**BUT**, it seems that gatsby bundle **ALL** Components into the production-build, which appear in the Directory-Structure!

**Why can I say this?**

I had a Map-Module which was replaced by another one. So I keep `Map.js` in my /Components-Folder, but fully remove the `leaflet` Packages from my `package.json` (even if Map.js requires leaflet)

I thought: "there is no place where I've import `Map.js`, so gatsby / webpack will not recognize the Component and don't need to build it".
But anyway, on doing `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build` I got this error:

[image: error on gatsby build]

This makes me aware that gatsby / webpack seems to parse every Component, regardless if referenced by `import` or not.

**Questions:**

Is there any way to archive, that only Components which are *really* imported in the Sourcecode are running through the build-process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out.
At least it was a lack of behavior throughout the build process of webpack / gatsby.

First I have to see that there are **two** build-processes:

1. my `gatsby-theme`
2. the page, which include my `gatsby-theme`

As the error appear at the build of the `gatsby-theme`, the error appear with webpack.
Webpack parse every file and try to generate production files out of it.
If there are missing dependencies (like above described) it stop with an error.

So if I put back leaflet-Packages to the package.json of `gatsby-theme` and bundle it, all work smooth like expected.

But if I import this `gatsby-theme` as base of my `site`-Project, does it will bundle leaflet in the build-files, even if not used?

**NO**

The reason is, that if I run `gatsby build` at my `site` Project, the build-process will recognize which components are **really** used by gatsby. And as the `Map` module isn't used anymore, it wont be put into the production code.